# Chrome get Set-cookie header but doesnt put it in a new requests

Tags: node.js, react-native, google-chrome, cookies, cors

I m working a Mobile app using **React Native** at the front end, NodeJs at the back end. I put an authentication mechanism for this app. Back-end works fine. I've tested with the postman. After login request with correct data, the server sends me a cookie in "**Set-cookie" header**. Then I put my next request header as "cookie" and I got my data. However, it works differently when I m working with React Native part. I m using **Chrome browser** to test app for now, and I can see that browser gets a set-cookie header with the response from Login request, (plus I've seen server created a new cookie with user info in it). But for the next request (say its "/home"), it doesn't send the cookie back, so the server doesn't recognize the user and creates a new cookie (with no user info in it) and returns 403 response.

There are some solutions that people suggest that you should do. I m sharing those here but none of them worked for me.

1. put with **withCredentials: true** in your request or axios object (didnt solve the problem)
2. set **httpOnly:false** for cookie in server (didnt solve the problem)
3. set corsOptions as var corsOptions = { origin: '*',credentials: true,**exposedHeaders: ["Set-Cookie"]**}; (still not working)
4. I also use **universal-cookie** library to reach cookie data from front end, but it also cannot reach the cookie value
5. Using **127.0.0.1 instead of "localhost"** in url also doesnt work (some says cookies dont work in first level domains)

Here is my React Native - Axios code

```
const axiosObj = axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:3000/",
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    responseType: 'json',
    withCredentials: true, 
  });

export function get(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        axiosObj.get(url).then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            return res.data
        })
    }) 
};

export function post(url,data){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        axiosObj.post(url,data).then(res => {
            console.log(res.headers)
            const cookies = new Cookies(res.headers.cookie);
        console.log("document cookie",document.cookie)    
        console.log(cookies.getAll()); 
            resolve(res)
        })
    }) 
}
```

At the back end here are the related codes

```
 var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser('keyboard cat'));


var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["Set-Cookie"]
 };
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//session settings
app.use(session({
  genid: (req) => {
    console.log('Inside the session middleware')
    console.log(req.sessionID)
    return uuidv4(); // use UUIDs for session IDs
  },
  store: new FileStore(),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { httpOnly: false,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + (30 * 86400 * 1000))}
}))
```

This is my session file at the server after Login

```
{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":2591995208,"expires":"2020-09-22T20:22:56.993Z","httpOnly":false,"path":"/"},"passport":{"user":{"_id":"5f307fc99f5c667918a56122","username":"test","__v":0}},"__lastAccess":1598214181785}
```

What can be the problem here? Any ideas?

edit :
I've learned that **not reaching "Set-cookie" is normal** from front-end (JS). (although in some websites, its said that you can put **httpOnly: false** in cookie settings and it solves this problem).
So it actually doesn't matter if I don't reach the header inside the front end code. I got "set-cookie" header in my response header and **chrome doesn't recognize the cookie and put it in cookies section in f12 (also doesn't set it in req.header).** That's the problem here

Edit 2:  I have some ideas about my problem.

- Since I m working with React Native and its not supposed to work in the Chrome browser, it might somehow cause that the browser is not setting cookies. I will create a react project and try to reach the cookie from there. => **I solved the problem it was not related to that issue. Although I solved problem when I was testing with react an app**
- I got a "service-worker.js" error with my react-native code. It doesn't look like it affects the functionality of the code but it might be somehow affected this cookie situation => **After solving the problem I still got this error, so it was not related to this.**

I also tried a react native app for cookies (react-native-cookie) but it has codes only working with android or ios so it didn't work for the browser.

Comment: Browsers block frontend JavaScript code from accessing the Set-Cookie header. Browsers are required by the Fetch spec to block frontend code from accessing it; the Fetch spec requires that blocking. See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name, where Set-Cookie is defined as a **forbidden response-header name** that must be filtered out from any response exposed to frontend code. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Comment: I just did a bit researching through the "set-cookie" header and it looks like setting **httpOnly:false should solve the problem that access problem with Js (front-end)** and cookies are set with set-cookie header (didnt see any other header i can use). So it must be a way to use set-cookie with JS. Although if everything works fine, i didnt have to reach that cookie. **Chrome should set it for responses automatically.** In my case its not. Thats the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problems. It looks like i have 2 problems with my code. First one is in server with cors settings. The first version was like this :

```
var cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  credentials: true,
  exposedHeaders: ["set-cookie"]
 };
app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

So basically I was using the cors module for settings. When I create a React app for the test I got a cors error(origin error). Somehow my cors settings didn't work with the library. So I changed this code with the below.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
     // Website you wish to allow to connect
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
     // Request methods you wish to allow
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
     // Request headers you wish to allow
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin,X-Requested-With,content-type,set-cookie');
     // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
     // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
     res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  
     // Pass to next layer of middleware
     next();
   });
```

and I still had some cors error. One other reason you might get a cors error is that chromes same-origin policy. I m using windows 10 so I opened search bar below and paste there

```
 chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

A new chrome browser opened with no web security policy. Then my react app worked fine.I could reach the cookie using **document.cookie**, also in f12 under application tab >> cookies, I could be able to see my cookie. So google chrome saved my cookie. In the same chrome window, I run my react native app and it also worked successfully. So I thought it was only because security policy of chrome and change my cors settings back and I started to get an error again.

So in conclusion, I had to change 2 things.

1. **Cors module didn't work, I set headers manually and they worked fine.**
2. **I had to disable Chrome's same-origin policy**

Comment: I had same issue but using cors with default options works for me. Not sure running with security disabled is the way to go though. Did you encounter any issue after deployment related to cookies?

Comment: This isn't a solution, this is a security hack.